# Como construir um json em powershell

Tags: powershell

Estou criando um script em Powershell que chama o método POST de uma API REST.

No Body envio uma string que representa um objeto JSON com os parâmetros que serão inseridos pela API.

Sabem como posso fazer escape em Powershell de uma string que representa um objeto JSON?

Excerto do script que tenho:

```
$jsonStr = "{""Nickname"":""$nickname"", ""Type"" : ""$type""}"

$content = New-Object System.Net.Http.StringContent $jsonStr

$content.Headers.ContentType = "application/json"

$task = $client.PostAsync($uriPost.Replace("{profid}", $profileId), $content)

$result = $task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

Só que assim, se o nickname tiver uma " ou / vai dar erro. Como posso fazer escape ao `jsonStr`?

---

**Solução:**

Acho que consegui uma solução:

```
    $userProperties = @{
        nick = $name
        type = $type 
    }

    $jsonPayload = $userProperties | ConvertTo-Json
```

O convertTo-Json jã faz o escape necessário.

Comment: Que erro que acontece? Não tem nenhum problema no script em si, a barra fica normal dentro do JSON

Comment: No script acima nem / estou inserindo. Não faço qualquer tipo de escape.

Comment: @Lucy, normalmente quando voce mesmo acha a solucao, voce posta como uma resposta e marca esta como solucao aceita por voce. Assim as pessoas que tiverem a mesma duvida consigam achar a resposta aceita mais rapido :)

Answer (score 1):

Da pra fazer `escape` do valor das suas variáveis usando a função:

```
[System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape
```

Antes de montar o seu `JSON`, chame essa função para os valores das suas variáveis, deixando algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$nickname = [System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape('"teste"')
$jsonStr = "{""Nickname"": ""$nickname""}"
Write $jsonStr
```

O resultado vai ser este:

```
{"Nickname": "&quot;teste&quot;"}
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta, solucionei o problema com o ConvertToJson a partir de um dicionário.

Answer (score 0):

Essa eh a maneira de escapar as aspas em powershell pra criar uma string que representa seu json

```
$jsonStr =@"
{"Nickname":"$nickname", "Type" : "$type"}
"@
```